# CMake: Store build/system information in binary

Tags: cmake

How do I store basic information, like system name (`Linux`), used compiler `gcc`) or architecture (`x86_64`), in a file that I include into my binary?

All the code for writing such a `.in` file is already there, except that the relevant CMake variables are all empty, e.g. `CMAKE_SYSTEM` or `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`:

```
set(NEWLINE "\\\\n")
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/update_buildflags.cmake "
file(WRITE \${DST} \"#define BUILDFLAGS \\\" 
     ARCH=\${CMAKE_SYSTEM}${NEWLINE} 
     COMP=\${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}${NEWLINE} 
     BUILD=\${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}${NEWLINE}\\\"\n\")")    
add_custom_target(update_buildflags COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
     -DDST=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/buildflags.c
     -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/update_buildflags.cmake)
```

This custom target is then added as dependency for the main binary and the resulting file `src/buildflags.c` looks like this:

```c
#define BUILDFLAGS " ARCH=\n COMP=\n BUILD=\n"
```

Why are the used CMake variables empty although printing them with `message()` shows the correct information?

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM: Linux-4.4.0-92-generic
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an template file to make it more readable.

- Pro: Not necessary to write the whole file within cmake
- Pro: Easy to edit
- Contra: Additional file

Example src/autocode/buildflags.h.in:

```
#ifndef BUILD_FLAGS_H
#def BUILD_FLAGS_H  
#define ARCH ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}
#define COMP ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
#define BUILD ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} 
// Add more of your stuff here
#define APP_BUILD_WITH_CMAKE_VERSION "${CMAKE_VERSION}"
#define APP_BUILD_ON_PLATFORM "${CMAKE_SYSTEM}"
#endif // BUILD_FLAGS_H
```

In your CMakeLists.txt

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/autocode/buildflags.h.in 
               ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/buildflags.h)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

In your code

```
#include "buildflags.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '\' before the $ when accessing CMAKE_... variables. Works like a charm afterwards.

Comment: I think using a template is cleaner.  This is, after all, what they were made for.