# Variable substition via regex

Tags: c++, regex, cmake

How would I perform configuration via substitution from CMake `configure_file()` or Autoconf file configuration (going from `*.in` to just `*`) as a regex for each variable?
I just want to be able to do this in a build system I'm working on.

For example, with `foobar.in`:

```
#define EMAIL "@DEV_EMAIL@\@@DEV_DOMAIN@"
```

I want `foobar`:

```
#define EMAIL "fubar\@foobar.com"
```

How would I go about accomplishing this? Something like this? (Linux box)

```
/@<VAR>@/<VALUE>/g
```

However, I want to be able to escape the `@` character. How would I ignore the escaped characters?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by `regex for each variable`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: For example you might have a file `foo.hpp.in` which has `@FOO_BAR_IS_DEFINED@` in it. I want to substitute it safely, for any such variable, via a regex.

Comment: Still doesn't get meaning of `regex` in given situation. Can you provide more complete example **in the question post**? Describe which variables are defined and to which values, content of `.in` file, and content of the output file you want to produce.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523411/cmake-store-build-system-information-in-binary